# Regex matching emoticons

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji, emoticons

We are working on a project where we want users to be able to use both emoji syntax (like `:smile:`, `:heart:`, `:confused:`,`:stuck_out_tongue:`) as well as normal emoticons (like `:)`, `<3`, `:/`, `:p`)

I'm having trouble with the emoticon syntax because sometimes those character sequences will occur in:

- normal strings or URL's - **http`:/`/example.com**
- within the emoji syntax - **`:p`encil:**

How can I find these emoticon character sequences but not when other characters are near them?

The entire regex I'm using for all the emoticons is huge, so here's a trimed down version:

```
(\:\)|\:\(|<3|\:\/|\:-\/|\:\||\:p)
```

You can play with a demo of it in action here: http://regexr.com/3a8o5

Comment: Why not split it up in multiple regexes? Also, what you could do is match with boundaries, for example `/\b:\)\b/`

Comment: If I remember correctly, both [Twemoji](https://github.com/twitter/twemoji/) and [Emojione](https://github.com/Ranks/emojione/tree/master/lib/js) provide JS code to do that with their image sets and there are dozens of implementations of the same thing on Github, NPM, bower etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Match emoji first (to take care of the :pencil: example) and then check for a terminating whitespace or newline:

```
(\:\w+\:|\<[\/\\]?3|[\(\)\\\D|\*\$][\-\^]?[\:\;\=]|[\:\;\=B8][\-\^]?[3DOPp\@\$\*\\\)\(\/\|])(?=\s|[\!\.\?]|$)
```

This regex matches the following (preferring emoji) returning the match in matching group 1:

```
:( :) :P :p :O :3 :| :/ :\ :$ :* :@
:-( :-) :-P :-p :-O :-3 :-| :-/ :-\ :-$ :-* :-@
:^( :^) :^P :^p :^O :^3 :^| :^/ :^\ :^$ :^* :^@
): (: $: *:
)-: (-: $-: *-:
)^: (^: $^: *^:
<3 </3 <\3
:smile: :hug: :pencil:
```

It also supports terminal punctuation as a delimiter in addition to white space.

You can see more details and test it here: https://regex101.com/r/aM3cU7/4

Comment: Yep! I already have the emoticon selection working but the key here is adding `(?=\s|[\!\.\,\?]|$)` at the end of my existing regex.   Thanks!

Comment: When matching `(` or `)` you should also check that it isn't part of a valid set of parenthesis, for example you don't want this to match the `8)` emoticon here: `blah blah bug (reproduced on iOS 8)`. In short, this really isn't something you can handle well with regex.

Comment: It looks like any character followed by a `:` also matches (`A:`, `~:`, `H:`, etc). Don't think that's what you want. Also misses all but the last in a set of repeated emoticons (`(:(:(:(:` or `:);):)`).

Answer (score 2):

Make a [positive look-ahead for a space](http://regexr.com/3a8p6)

```
([\:\<]-?[)(|\\/pP3D])(?:(?=\s))
 |       |      |         |
 |       |      |         |
 |       |      |         |-> match last separating space
 |       |      |-> match last part of the emot
 |       |-> it may have a `-` or not 
 |-> first part of the emoticon
```

Since you're using javascript, and you don't have access to look arounds:

```
/([\:\<]-?[)|\\/pP3D])(\s|$)/g.exec('hi :) ;D');
```

And then just `splice()` the resulting array out of its last entry (that's most probably a space)

Answer (score 1):

I assume these emoticons will commonly be used with spaces before and after. Then `\s` might be what you're looking for, as it represents a white space.

Then your regex would become

```
\s+(\:\)|\:\(|<3|\:\/|\:-\/|\:\||\:p)\s
```

Answer (score 0):

You want regex look-arounds regarding spacing.  Another answer here suggested a positive look-ahead, though I'd go double-negative:

```
(?<!\S)(\:\)|\:\(|<3|\:\/|\:-\/|\:\||\:p)(?!\S)
```

While JavaScript doesn't support `(?<!pattern)`, [look-behind can be mimicked](http://web.archive.org/web/20110716142419/http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript):

```
test_string.replace(/(\S)?(\:\)|\:\(|<3|\:\/|\:-\/|\:\||\:p)(?!\S)/,
                    function($0, $1) { return $1 ? $0 : replacement_text; });
```

All I did was prefix your code with `(?<!\S)` in front and suffix with`(?!\S)` in back.  The prefix ensures you do not follow a non-whitespace character, so the only valid leading entries are spaces or nothing (start of line).  The suffix does the same thing, ensuring you are not followed by a non-whitespace character.  See also this [more thorough regex walk-through](https://regex101.com/r/mF9tY0/1).

One of the comments to the question itself was suggesting `\b` (word boundary) markers.  I don't recommend these.  In fact, this suggestion would do the opposite of what you want; `\b:/` will indeed match `http://` since there is a word boundary between the `p` and the `:`.  This kind of reasoning would suggest `\B` (not a word boundary), e.g. `\B:/\B`.  This is more portable (it works with pretty much all regex parsers while look-arounds do not), and you can choose it in that case, but I prefer the look-arounds.

Comment: I'm using JavaScript and lookbehinds are not supported in JS :(

Comment: @ChrisBarr ah, good point.  Solved using a function for the replace call.  See the edit I just made.