# Match unicode emoji in python regex

Tags: python, regex, unicode, emoji

I need to extract the text between a number and an emoticon in a text

example text:

```
blah xzuyguhbc ibcbb bqw 2 extract1  ☺️ jbjhcb 6 extract2  bjvcvvv
```

output:

```
extract1
extract2
```

The regex code that I wrote extracts the text between 2 numbers, I need to change the part where it identifies the unicode emoji characters and extracts text between them.

```
(?<=[\s][\d])(.*?)(?=[\d])
```

Please suggest a python friendly method, and I need it to work with all the emoji's not only the one's given in the example

https://regex101.com/r/uT1fM0/1

Comment: You should check out this stack to get the regex for emoticons http://stackoverflow.com/q/28077049/4639336

Comment: @reticentroot I do not think it will work for utf8 emoticons like "".

Comment: @reticentroot I need it to work with unicode emoticons.

Comment: can you convert the unicode emoji to text first before matching the emoji? This post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707222/print-python-emoji-as-unicode-string does that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are a lot of emoji [with different unicode values](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode), you have to explicitly specify them in your regex, or if they are with a spesific range you can use a character class. In this case your second simbol is not a standard emoji, it's just a unicode character, but since it's greater than `\u263a` (the unicode representation of ☺️) you can put it in a range with `\u263a`:

```
In [71]: s = 'blah xzuyguhbc ibcbb bqw 2 extract1  ☺️ jbjhcb 6 extract2  bjvcvvv'

In [72]: regex = re.compile(r'\d+(.*?)(?:\u263a|\U0001f645)')

In [74]: regex.findall(s)
Out[74]: [' extract1  ', ' extract2 ']
```

Or if you want to match more emojies you can use a character range (here is a good reference which shows you the proper range for different emojies  http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode):

```
In [75]: regex = re.compile(r'\d+(.*?)[\u263a-\U0001f645]')

In [76]: regex.findall(s)
Out[76]: [' extract1  ', ' extract2 ']
```

Note that in second case you have to make sure that all the characters withn the aforementioned range are emojies that you want.

Here is another example:

```
In [77]: s = "blah 4 xzuyguhbc  ibcbb bqw 2 extract1  ☺️ jbjhcb 6 extract2  bjvcvvv"

In [78]: regex = re.compile(r'\d+(.*?)[\u263a-\U0001f645]')

In [79]: regex.findall(s)
Out[79]: [' xzuyguhbc ', ' extract1  ', ' extract2 ']
```

Comment: I need it to work with all the emoji's not only the one's given in the example

Comment: @LeDerp As I mentioned, in that case you have to use a character range.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my stab at the solution. Not sure if it will work in all circumstances. The trick is to convert all unicode emojis into normal text. This could be done by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707222/print-python-emoji-as-unicode-string) Then you can match the emoji just as any normal text. Note that it won't work if the *literal* strings `\u` or `\U` is in your searched text.

Example: Copy your string into a file, let's call it `emo`. 
In terminal:

```
Chip chip@ 03:24:33@ ~: cat emo | python stackoverflow.py
blah xzuyguhbc ibcbb bqw 2 extract1  \u263a\ufe0f jbjhcb 6 extract2 \U0001f645 bjvcvvv\n
------------------------
[' extract1  ', ' extract2 ']
```

Where `stackoverflow.py` file is:

```
import fileinput
a = fileinput.input();
for line in a:
    teststring = unicode(line,'utf-8')
    teststring = teststring.encode('unicode-escape')

import re
print teststring
print "------------------------"
m = re.findall('(?<=[\s][\d])(.*?)(?=\\\\[uU])', teststring)
print m
```

Answer (score 0):

So this may or not work depending on your needs. If you know the emoji's ahead of time though this will probably work, you just need a list of the types of emoticons to expect.

Anyway without more information, this is what I'd do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

my_regex = re.compile(r'\d\s*([^☺️|^]+)')

string = "blah xzuyguhbc ibcbb bqw 2 extract1  ☺️ jbjhcb 6 extract2  bjvcvvv"

m = my_regex.findall(string)
if m:
  print m
```

Comment: Then you're going to need a working list, the pattern for each emoji is different, its like saying i need to match every word in English and I need a single regex to do that.  Otherwise think of another pattern, perhaps you know that it's always a single word after the number then you could say get the next word after the number and not care about the emoji.