# How to add emojis to alphanumerics RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex, emoji

How can one add all emojis to alphanumerics in the RegEx, like this

```
pattern = r'\w+'
```

Comment: Have you checked out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39536390/match-unicode-emoji-in-python-regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `emoji` package (`pip install emoji`) to get the emoji set and combine it with `\w+` in this way: `(?:\w|<emoji_pattern>)+`:

```py
from emoji import UNICODE_EMOJI
import re

e_list = UNICODE_EMOJI.keys()
word_emoji_rx = re.compile(r"(?:\w|{})+".format("|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(e_list,key=len,reverse=True)))))
print(word_emoji_rx.findall(r'abc def ghi'))
# => ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

See a [Python demo](https://repl.it/repls/TraumaticLuminousDestination)